# Powershell Call cancelled

Tags: powershell, exception, interruption, powershell-v6.0

I was running `Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/CIMV2 -ClassName CIM_Component | Out-File -Encoding utf8 .\CIM_Component.txt` and received

```
Get-CimInstance : Call cancelled
At line:1 char:2
+ (Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/CIMV2 -ClassName CIM_DirectoryContai ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-CimInstance], CimException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041032,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstanceCommand
```

This was **not** cancelled from a keyboard interrupt. It simply... timed out?
I really don't know why it cancelled at all.

I was hoping someone else might know what happened that it threw the *Call cancelled* error.

It may simply be that the amount of information is just too much going threw the pipe that it... but, its not a out of memory error...

I have no idea!

Comment: The error shown is from a different command (using a different `-ClassName`

Answer (score 0):

***strong text***Hummm… See the below for potential edification...

[CIM_Component class](https://blogs.msmvps.com/richardsiddaway/2019/04/25/cim_component-class')

> I saw a question about the CIM_Component class and wondered what it
>   was.  So I tried it

```
Get-CimInstance -Namespace root\CIMV2 -ClassName CIM_Component | select -f 1 | fl *

# Results

GroupComponent : Win32_Directory (Name = "<directory path>")
PartComponent : CIM_DataFile (Name = "<file path>”)
PSComputerName :
CimClass : root/CIMV2:CIM_DirectoryContainsFile
CimInstanceProperties : {GroupComponent, PartComponent}
CimSystemProperties : Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimSystemProperties
```

> What you’ll get is a list of every file on your system – showing
>   folder in the  GroupComponent (parent) and File in the PartComponent
>   (child).
>
> The documentation is totally accurate and totally useless as it
>   explains that  you get a parent-child relationship but not what’s in
>   it!
>
> I’d strongly recommend against using this class – there are easier
>   ways to get  the information.

Comment: Yes but the question wasn't about CIM_Component, it was about why if you run the command and don't interrupt it, it throws a `Call cancelled` error after a few minutes. Cause the system cancelled it.  Why does this happen?  Cause I imagine this would happen with other commands too.